# Update a <ul> and use the first <li> as template with the clone function

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, clone

I receive a JSON string from Ajax in order to update a results list.
If it's a "See more" I append the list. If it's a new search I clear the list before.
A soon as the ajax call is triggered a loading `<li>` is added at the bottom of the list.
The `<li></li>` exposed below is simplified. I don't want to add each `<span></span>` and other element individuali but instead use the first `<li></li>` as a template for the coming results.

This is the simplified **HTML** code

```
<ul id="list">
<li>
   <span class="itemPriceSell">1234</span>
   <span class="itemPriceRent">56</span>
</li>
<li>
   <span class="itemPriceSell">9876</span>
   <span class="itemPriceRent">54</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is the **jQuery** function

```
function refreshResults(data) {
    var cloned = $('ul#list li:first').clone();
    filtersChanged() ? $('ul#list li:not(:last)').remove() : null
    $.each(data, function(index, hbid) {
        cloned.find('.itemPriceSell').text(hbid.sellprice);
        cloned.find('.itemPriceRent').text(hbid.rentprice);
        cloned.insertBefore('ul#list li:last');
        console.log(cloned);

    });
    $('ul#list li:last').remove();
}
```

**The Problem**
It appends only one `<li>` at the bottom of the `<ul>` with the last JSON value but I didn't manage to append the 10 results coming from the JSON. The console.log always outputs the same (the last JSON result inside as the sell and rent price)

Any help regarding my bug would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the template once for each item you want to insert, not just once before the loop starts.

Try something like this:

```
function refreshResults(data) {
    filtersChanged() ? $('ul#list li:not(:last)').remove() : null
    var template = $('ul#list li:first');
    $.each(data, function(index, hbid) {
        var cloned = template.clone();
        cloned.find('.itemPriceSell').text(hbid.sellprice);
        cloned.find('.itemPriceRent').text(hbid.rentprice);
        cloned.insertBefore('ul#list li:last');
        console.log(cloned);
    });
    $('ul#list li:last').remove();
}
```

By only cloning it once, your original code was taking the single cloned item, and repeatedly performing the following actions on it:

1. Updating the rent and sell prices (overwriting any previous prices you set)
2. Inserting it at the end of the list. According to the [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) docs, if the item you are inserting is already in the DOM, it will be **moved** to the new location, not cloned - so the item was being repeatedly moved to the end (where it already was)

Comment: Wow fast and accurate. Thank you